# How to set custom theme octopress in gh-pages?

Tags: themes, octopress

I install octopress with gh-pages and install custom theme, but theme not working - foozzi.github.io

But locally this theme working! localhost:4000
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you see it locally it means that you did generated the content correctly.

You need to do this:

```
# rebuild the theme
rake generate

# add & commit you changes to git
git add . && git commit -m "Updates..."

# Now deploy it to the server
rake deploy
```

---

Your current site does not have any theme

[image]